Magento Query on pdp page
i want to print and check query calling on pdp page how i can check that product query on product detail page?

You can enable the query log by running bin/magento dev:query-log:enable.
But this will log all queries with backtrace which consumes lot of server space.
So, open a PDP, enable the log, refresh the page, then disable the log with bin/magento dev:query-log:disable. Then you will see all queries with a debug trace in  var/debug/db.log

If you are working in local environment,
You can add a logger to print $sql inside the below file.
vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php
Place custom logger inside this function
public function query($sql, $bind = array())
{
    ............................

    // return the results embedded in the prepared statement object
    $stmt->setFetchMode($this->_fetchMode);
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info("Query->". $sql);

    return $stmt;
}

